# Different definitions of Lucas groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, definition, lucas-numbers

I see two different definitions of Lucas groups, stated below.

Is one of the two standard? Are they trivial variations?

---

From these [slides](https://math.boisestate.edu/reu/publications/NumberTheoryElliptic2017.pdf#page=23) (Liljana Babinkostova et al., Boise State University, 2017)

The Lucas roup for parameters $(D,N)$ is the set
$$\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\Bbb Z_N}^2,\ x^2-D\,y^2\equiv1\pmod N\bigr\}$$
with the group law defined by
$$(x_0,y_0)\cdot(x_1,y_1)=\\
\bigl((x_0\,x_1+D\,y_0\,y_1)\bmod N,\ (x_0\,y_1+y_0\,x_1)\bmod N\bigr)$$

---

From that [archived online course](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409201919/http://diamond.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/MATH308/LUCgroup.htm) (same source, 2016)

It is restricted to $D\ge5$ with $D+4$ a square, and $N\ge3$ coprime with $2D$.

The Lucas roup for parameters $(D,N)$ is the set
$$\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\Bbb Z_N}^2,\ x^2+D\,y^2\equiv4\pmod N\bigr\}$$
with the group law defined by
$$(x_0,y_0)*(x_1,y_1)=\\
\biggl(\frac{N+1}2(x_0\,x_1+D\,y_0\,y_1)\bmod N,\ \frac{N+1}2(x_0\,y_1+y_0\,x_1\bmod N\biggr)$$